# 404 (Not Found) play local video file ionic cordova

Tags: cordova, webview, html5-video, ionic4, local-files

I am attempting to use a normal video tag to play a locally saved video file on both android and ios using cordova/ionic/angular. I have spent hours and hours on this issue, and cannot get anything to play. PLEASE HELP! this is my code. I have confirmed in multiple ways that the video file exists. Each of these checkDirs return true.

```
  this.file.checkDir(this.file.dataDirectory, 'ja_JP').then(res => {
        this.file.checkDir(this.file.dataDirectory + 'ja_JP/', '994007046').then(resp2 => {
          this.file.checkFile(this.file.dataDirectory + 'ja_JP/' + '994007046/', 'c2f5f11b-45c5- 
             4c15-9b04-a8aedb24a06f.mp4').then(resp3 => {
               if (resp3) {
                  this.dialogVideoPath = (this.file.dataDirectory + 'ja_JP/' + '994007046/' + 
                 'c2f5f11b-45c5-4c15-9b04-a8aedb24a06f.mp4');
                  // This doesn't work, this gives me a 404, but I have confirmed the file does 
                 exist at this path.

  (http://10.0.0.44:8100/data/user/0/com.missionlanguage.tall/files/ja_JP/994007303/e26bc992-db60-4908-ba5f-8749f506326f.mp4)

                 // stripping 'file://' from the beginning doesn't work (404)
                 // leaving 'file://' doesn't work either. resp: not allowed to load local 
                resource

(file:///data/user/0/com.missionlanguage.tall/files/ja_JP/994007046/c2f5f11b-45c5-4c15-9b04-a8aedb24a06f.mp4)

                }

            this.file.readAsDataURL(this.file.dataDirectory + 'ja_JP/' + '994007046/', 'c2f5f11b-45c5-4c15-9b04-a8aedb24a06f.mp4').then(resp4 => {
              // USING THIS base64 RESPONSE DOESNT WORK EITHER
            })
          })
        })
      })
```